# Error message in ANSYS Fluent setup

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, meshing, fluent

While trying to run a simulation in ANSYS Fluent, I am getting this error message : Error at Node 0: Normalized key of 26982 is out of range [0, 27030]. This error message comes when I try to run the simulation after loading the mesh and setting up boundary in Fluent setup.
I tried some changes in my mesh, still getting same error.
What could be the possible issue?. Sorry, if my question is too basic. I am just a beginner in ANSYS.
I am using ANSYS 2023 R1 (student).